# Where to use WITH?

Tags: neo4j

In this query I have a:

```
        START root = node(*)
        MATCH root-[:HAS_DEPARTMENTS]->()<-[:IS_DEPARTMENT]-department-[relationship1:HAS_CATEGORY_SUGGESTION]->categorySuggestion-[relationship2:IS_CATEGORY_SUGGESTION]->()<-[:HAS_CATEGORY_SUGGESTIONS]-root
        WHERE root.name = "Store" and department.name = "foo" and categorySuggestion.name = "bar"
        DELETE relationship1, relationship2

        WITH root, department, categorySuggestion
        MATCH root-[:HAS_CATEGORIES]->categories
        CREATE department-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->categorySuggestion
        CREATE categories<-[:IS_CATEGORY]-categorySuggestion
```

I have a WITH clause separating two parts.

If I move the DELETE down below WITH I will get an error.

I just wonder, how will I know where I should use WITH.

Are there some golden rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WITH clause separates the different piped statements of a cypher query. After a WITH, the following parts have only visibility of the variables named in the WITH clause. Unless you are stating them in the WITH, your DELETE will therefore fail.